# Flask, flask-login from sends session and remember_me cookies under single set-cookie header

Tags: flask, cors, flask-login

Trying to implement authentication on a flask app, but the session cookie does not work because my login endpoint returns a response where one "set-cookie" header contains 2 cookies - "session" and "remember_me" - which are managed internally by flask and flask-login respectively.

For reference, the value of the "set-cookie" field is something like:
`remember_token=[CONTENTS]; Expires=[DATE]; HttpOnly; Path=/;session=[CONTENT]; HttpOnly; Path=/`
of course simply concatenating 2 cookies together does not parse on the client side as 2 cookies.

Is there any way to get flask to send those cookies under separate 'set-cookie' headers?

For context, flask is being used as an API.

Tried intercepting the response through the "after_this_request" decorator and then manually parsing the string to separate cookies, but it seems there is no access to the "set-cookie" field that way.